# Passing login info when sending HttpRequest to SFDC Web Service

Tags: c#, authentication, salesforce, httprequest

Trying to send JSON HttpRequest to SFDC Web Service, get following response:

```
[1]
0:  {
message: "Session expired or invalid"
errorCode: "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
}
```

How correctly pass session id or another information from LoginResult with HttpRequest? Code sample follows:

```
    // Generate JSON
    MyClass object = new MyClass();
    string post_data = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(object);   // this is what we are sending

    // this is where we will send it
    string uri = "https://url.salesforce.com/some_path/";

    // create a request
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.Method = "POST";
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

    // Setup proxy and SFDC login
    LoginResult result = SfdcConnection.GetLoginResult();
    // ------------ Need to add login info here -----------------

    // now send it
    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    // grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    string jsonResponse = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: it will depend on exactly which api you're trying to call, what the actual url you're making a request to ?

Comment: Sorry, did not mention - REST

Comment: Found some documentation, seems need to send auth request first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the sessionId in the Authorization header, using the oauth pattern, so it'd be

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.sessionId);
```

The sessionId is usable for quite some time, so just call login once, not before each REST api call.

This covered in more detail in the [REST API docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `LoginResult` (which most likely contains the session ID) to your request, otherwise, the web service just sees a request with no session ID (and no cookies either), and has no way of verifying that you are the client that logged in.

pseudocode

```
LoginResult result = SfdcConnection.GetLoginResult();
// attach sesionId to your request, see the web services documentation for this
request.Headers.Add("sessionId", result.sessionId);
```

Comment: Ya nee znayu Aleksey, I just used "sessionId" as a default. You need to look at the API documentation for the correct naming.

Comment: Does not work: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: `SfdcConnection.GetLoginResult();` You are probably supposed to attach some API key to the login request. As I said before, consult the API documentation.

Comment: If You do not know why You'd answered? Have not found documentation for this only for SOAP requests.